# body.scrollTop is deprecated?

Tags: jquery

I am using `jQuery` version `1.7.2`

I found these lines in Google Chrome Developer Tools:

```
body.scrollTop is deprecated in strict mode. Please use 'documentElement.scrollTop' if in strict mode and 'body.scrollTop' only if in quirks mode. jquery-1.7.2.min.js:4
body.scrollLeft is deprecated in strict mode. Please use 'documentElement.scrollLeft' if in strict mode and 'body.scrollLeft' only if in quirks mode. jquery-1.7.2.min.js:4
event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead. jquery-1.7.2.min.js:3
```

Is that an error or is it normal? Does it affect my website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are facing is general one for chrome.....it uses `body.scrollTop` to represent the view-port's scroll position in standards mode.

Possible reason i can think of is that the makers of chrome want the developers to switch to more formal or universal style of coding....as for other browsers like Mozilla, I don't think your problem would be there (have you checked in other browsers too !!? looks fine on my mozilla.

**[Try this Fix](https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/643)**

Comment: its just on chrome other browsers are fine

Comment: @user3059001:There is the link for fix above. You can give it a try.

Comment: Chrome wants to match the HTML spec and other browsers' behavior. http://stackoverflow.com/a/20060513/822138

Answer (score 0):

No it is not a problem. It is just a suggestion. Although it is a best practice to use the latest version of jQuery. So in my opinion you should update to the latest version.

Comment: hmm ill update it now and let u know

Comment: same problem i think ill leave it