# webkit scroll top no longer working

Tags: javascript, webkit

Scroll top is no longer working for me in chrome annd other -webkit- browsers by the looks of it. I'm wanting to simply scroll to anchor.

```
$('body').animate({
    'scrollTop':   $('#about').offset().top
}, 1000);
```

It's outputting this to the console, I havnt turned strict mode on.

```
body.scrollTop is deprecated in strict mode. 
Please use 'documentElement.scrollTop' if in strict mode
and 'body.scrollTop' only if in quirks mode.
```

Comment: So why not do what it says? ;) isn't this just a warning anyway and not a TypeError, so your code should still work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21231137/body-scrolltop-is-deprecated

Comment: body.scrolltop also doesnt work. The body is what im trying to scroll is it not?