# body.scrollTop is deprecated in strict mode. Please use 'documentElement.scrollTop' if in strict mode and 'body.scrollTop' only if in quirks mode.

Tags: javascript, jquery, deprecated

I'm receiving the error:

body.scrollTop is deprecated in strict mode. Please use 'documentElement.scrollTop' if in strict mode and 'body.scrollTop' only if in quirks mode.

My code is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //Animates Scrolling to anchor
    function scrollToAnchor(aid){
        var divTag = $("div[name='"+ aid +"']");
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: divTag.offset().top},'slow');
    }

    //If Checking out as guest, scroll to Shipping Information
    $("#ReadDescription").click(function() {
        scrollToAnchor('longdescreadmore');
    });

});
```

How can I edit my code to use this documentElement.ScrollTop?

Comment: considered using document.scrollTop instead of scrollTop ?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19635188/why-is-body-scrolltop-deprecated

Comment: You are looking for `document.documentElement`. That's the element created by the `<html>` tag.

Comment: @DaggNabbit That confused me. Heh. Where do I put this at?

Comment: @user2433689 I guess you'd want `$('html')` instead of `$('html,body')` in strict mode.

Comment: @DaggNabbit That's it? I don't add document.documentElement anywhere?

Comment: @user2433689 that's why I said document.documentElement referred to the element created by the html tag ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Dagg Nabbit gave the solution. Change

```
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: divTag.offset().top},'slow');
```

to

```
$('html').animate({scrollTop: divTag.offset().top},'slow');
```

if you want to avoid the deprecation warning in Chrome. ([Why is `body.scrollTop` deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19635188/822138))

It works because `documentElement` is the `html` node:

```
$('html')[0] === document.documentElement //-> true
$('body')[0] === document.body            //-> true
```

But your code is working now (albeit with a warning) and it will keep working when Chrome removes the "quirky" behavior. You **shouldn't** change your code if you want to continue supporting browsers that use `body.scrollTop` to represent the scrolling viewport in standards mode (older Chrome and Safari, I think).

Comment: Sam is right. If you leave the `body` part out of the selector, Safari 7.0.1 (and probably others) won't scroll anywhere.

Comment: So the point here is - don't change the code to suppress the warning?

Comment: @Jon, code like this is already targeting both the standard and nonstandard behavior (`html,body`), so it doesn't need to be changed.