# Chrome scrollTop strickt mode issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I suddenly had the following stop working:

Html

```
<a id="scrollTop" href="#">Scroll</a>
```

jquery

```
 $("#scrollTop").on("click", function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 'slow');
 });
```

If I check in console I get this message

> body.scrollTop is deprecated in strict mode. Please use 'documentElement.scrollTop' if in strict mode and 'body.scrollTop' only if in quirks mode.

But I haven't changed anything so I don't get it. [I did check on other SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21268450/body-scrolltop-is-deprecated-in-strict-mode-please-use-documentelement-scrollt) but it still doesn't work and more importantly I don't understand why it sudden started doing this

Comment: It means the script is parsed using strict mode (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode). Is your script by any chance concatenated?

Comment: why you are using e.preventDefault() ?

Comment: @Sora regardless, it won't work

Comment: @Anzeo nope, that jQuery block stands by itself

Comment: It is a warning not a error. It still works for me. http://jsfiddle.net/96Dtm/

Comment: Also it works and without e.preventDefault(); http://jsfiddle.net/96Dtm/1/

Comment: did you make sure that you are loading your jquery script in the head section of the page ?

Comment: damn! I had overflow-x on css. Shouldn't be using overflow when doing that. Removed it and page is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had overflow-x on body in css. 
Shouldn't be using overflow on body when doing that (scrollTop). Removed it and page is working