# body.scrollTop is deprecated in strict mode.

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I want a smooth scroll to internal links. Works fine in firefox, but in Chrome I get an error "body.scrollTop is deprecated in strict mode"

My code was

```
$(function() {
   $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
      if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') 
       && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
         var target = $(this.hash);
         target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
         if (target.length) {
            $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: target.offset().top}, 1000);
            return false;
         }
      }
   });
});
```

The problem, however, is after I changed this

`$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: target.offset().top}, 1000);`

to

`$('html').animate({scrollTop: target.offset().top}, 1000);`

the links don't work at all, and there is no error / warning in the console.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21268450/body-scrolltop-is-deprecated-in-strict-mode-please-use-documentelement-scrollt

Comment: @RyanPilbeam The solution mentioned there is to change $('html,body') to $('html') which is precisely my problem - the old code works in Firefox & not in chrome, but after changing it, it doesn't work in either, with no error / warning

Comment: I can't imagine why there would be a strict mode error about a DOM property.

Comment: ...and I don't get that error in Chrome. http://jsfiddle.net/qr9z7/1/ Which versions of jQuery and Chrome are you using?

Comment: @cookiemonster getting the same warning in that fiddle. jQuery 2.1.0, Chrome Version 32.0.1700.107 m.

Comment: I get the same error in that fiddle, same version, but not here: http://jsfiddle.net/98pNu/1/

Comment: I'm using Chrome  31, so that must be the difference.

Comment: @RyanPilbeam: You removed `body` from the selector.

Comment: Not working, with warning: 
 $('html,body')  // this works in firefox 

Not working, no warning 
$('html') 
or even 
$(document.documentElement)

Comment: As a temporary solution, you could wrap the call in a `try/catch`.

Comment: Chrome 32 at least said that body.scrollTop was depreciated and to use documentElement.scrollTop (which by the way doesn't do crap either). I updated to Chrome 33 today and now the error is gone, and the link just doesn't move. Great..

Answer (score 0):

Keep `'html,body'` to target more browsers.

As long as Chrome is showing the "deprecated" warning (not an error), it's still responding to `body.scrollTop` and should be scrolling like you expect.

I think the confusion is because Chrome 32 warns about the deprecated feature but Chrome 33 uses **only** the deprecated feature with no warning.