# Scroll to same Position on reload and load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have a webpage that is full of div's with huge length, so whenever I **refresh** my page or **manual document loading** through actions, i need to scroll my window or document to same or previous position, but i want that to be done by browser automatically.

i searched it in web and found no help, but i came to know that solution is there with out any other lib inclusion.

I have a page of height more exceeds window height with some divs and select boxes whenever i select any thing in middle of page, it refresh my page and sends loads new document **here** i want to move to my previously selected select box placed div so that i can avoid manual scrolling on each selection

Comment: any chance you can set up a jsfiddle so we can get an idea of the layout?

Comment: you can see my count i'm new to this stackoverflow and fiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/, it's a site that will allow you to copy some css, html and javascript in. It will help when looking at your problem. Once you hit save, just post the url here.

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/ in Stackoverflow.. :D

Comment: just check this page move the first answer  to top of page and press f5 button you will get the same position again... that i want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> first i added position to **localStorage**

```
localStorage.setItem("scrollTop", document.body.scrollTop);
```

> then getting same position from it onload(reload)

```
window.onload = function() {  
var scroll = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("scrollTop"));
//parseInt(localStorage.scrollTop);   
if (!isNaN(scroll))
document.body.scrollTop = scroll;
```

}

Comment: Why do you cast `document.body.scrollTop` to a `string`, and then cast it back to an `int` again? You can just store `document.body.scrollTop` without any casting, and then when you get it back again you won't need to use `parseInt`.

Comment: Actually it looks like `localStorage.setItem()` casts `int`s to a `string` (in Chrome anyway).

Comment: Along with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19635188/why-is-body-scrolltop-deprecated) I would not recommend using scrollTop and scrollLeft

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand, the refresh of the page is not automatic and is completely dependent on the user. So, one solution that comes to my mind is use the [local storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) that's built into the browser and update that storage with your `pos` variable periodically.

Sample code snippet (taken from documentation directly - pure javascript):

```
 // Store
 localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
// Retrieve
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("lastname");
```

That way you can retrieve the last saved scroll position and do the needful. Jquery also has a [local storage API](http://plugins.jquery.com/tag/localstorage/) built around this HTML5 webstorage. I've posted the documentation, it should get you started in the right direction.

Comment: I hope it helps. If it worked for you ,please mark the answer as accepted so that other users stumbling upon this question can also benefit out of the solution. Better still, update the question with relevant code snippet that worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

### Getting the scroll position

In JavaScript, we can use the `window.scollY` & `window.scollX` object to get the scroll data.

```js
scrollFromTop = document.body.scrollY;
```

### Not Forgetting the position

We need to add the position to a **localStorage** variable, so that we don't lose the data when the user goes onto a different page

```js
localStorage.setItem("scrollY", window.scrollY);
```

### Getting data from the `localStorage`

To get data from the `localStorage`, we must use the `localStorage.getItem()` method, like this.

```js
var data = localStorage.getItem(nameOfItem);
```

### Setting the value on load

On load, get the original position that we have set earlier, and then scroll down to it using `window.scroll`

```js
window.onload = function() {  
    var scrollY = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("scrollY"));
    if (!isNaN(scroll)) {
        window.scroll(0, scrollY);
    }
}
```

### Full Code

Here is the full JavaScript code for this question:

```js
window.onunload = function() {
    localStorage.setItem("scrollY", window.scrollY);
}

window.onload = function() {  
    var scrollY = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("scrollY"));
    if (!isNaN(scroll)) {
        window.scroll(0, scrollY);
    }
}
```

### Documentation Links

[localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

[scrollX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollX)

[scrollY](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollY)

Answer (score 0):

> This is how i have solved this issue

```
function scrollWin() {
    var scrolledTo = localStorage.getItem('scrolledTo');
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: scrolledTo }, 50);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    scrollWin();
});

$(window).scroll(function (event) {
    var scrolledTo = $(window).scrollTop();
    localStorage.setItem('scrolledTo', scrolledTo);
});
```