# Change Favicon without reloading or changing the page

Tags: css, web, scroll, favicon

I wonder if it was possible to change the favicon without reloading or changing the page.
I want to have the first favicon when the `document.body.scrollTop < 100` and when it's > 100 I want to have the second favicon and that witout changing or reloading the page.

I didn't found anything about it on the internet so if someone could help me !

Comment: What have you tried ?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the favicon icon by changing the `href` of the favicon link, the page won't be reloaded:

Also, try to use `window.scrollY` or `document.documentElement.scrollTop` instead since `document.body.scrollTop` seems to be [deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19635188/why-is-body-scrolltop-deprecated).

```
var link = document.querySelector("link[rel~='icon']");

function runOnScroll(element){
    if(document.documentElement.scrollTop > 100){
        element.href = '/assets/test2.ico';
    }else{
        element.href = '/assets/test1.ico';

    }
}

window.addEventListener(
  "scroll",
  () => runOnScroll(link),
  { passive: true }
);
```

Assuming you've already added the favicon in your html `head` tag: (If not, you can create a new link element dynamically as well)

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/assets/test1.ico">
```